# Is it fine to use `[]` notation in formulas?

Tags: notation

`[]` is used in most programming languages to define a variable as an array. In a mathematical formula, is it fine to indicate the symbol I am using is an array, if yes how can I achieve it?

For that reason, could I use `[]` next to a symbol definition or should I use symbols without using any `[]`?

---

For example:

---

$N$:    Data files used by job $j$: $N = \{n_{1},n_{2},\dotsc,n_{\lvert N\rvert}\}$
$A^{}_{{\!N}}[\,]$ :  Array of required run time to store data files in $N$.

I refer to

$A^{}_{{\!N}} =
                                       \{a^{}_{{1}},a^{}_{{2}},\dotsc,a^{}_{{\lvert N\rvert}}\}$ as $A[]$.

$C(A_N[]) = \sum_{n \in N}{A_n}$

Comment: As long as you define it first I don’t see a problem.

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  What are your indices inside the array?  The $n_0, \cdots, n_N$ I mean.  And surely you don't mean to sum over $A_n$, whatever that means, in the final sum?  Did you mean $a_n$?  Something else?

Comment: Is $A[]$ an array or is it a function on an array?  (or both?)

Comment: I think it might clarify things if you were to give a clear, consistent example of the sort of definition(s) you'd like to make.  Be as detailed as possible.  As a general rule, it's fine to introduce notation but unless it is universally familiar it is necessary to explain clearly what your notation means.

Comment: For what its worth, it is more common in mathematics to refer to it as a sequence rather than an array... and to refer to it as $A_N$ or as $(A_N)$ or similar.  That being said, there is a common enough overlap between programmers and mathematicians that most people would be fine understanding your notation that it probably shouldn't matter.  Your indices could use some work though... I would much sooner have them labeled $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N$

Comment: @lulu I updated my quation hoping it will be clearer. `A[]` is an array, but its each item refers to a different object. Like $A_1$ is data-1’s value, $A_2$ is data-2’s value and so on. Its indices are `0,1,2,3 …N`.

Comment: Still not clear.  As I asked before, are the $A_n$ the same as the $a_n$?

Comment: Some scholars (including myself) use $f(x)$ to define a function of a *continuous* variable and $f[x]$ to define a function of a *discrete* variable, but this is not a universal convention.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry for not being clear, I think I am kind of lost in representing what I think as a programmer in a correct mathematical perspective. I was trying to represent the iteration on the array that I refer as $A_N$. Hoping to say that `A_{n_{1}}` is (data_1’s value), `A_{n_{2}}` is (data_2’s value) … But I am not sure how should I refer it inside the sum notation as : $\sum_{n \in N}{a_n}$ or $\sum_{n \in N}{A_n}$.

Comment: As JMoravitz already said: $\sum_{n \in N}{a_n}$ is perfect. In a math paper we don't need `[]` because you want it to be read by humans and presumably not by a compiler.